# monic irreducible polynomial over K

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

If $F/K$ is a field extension, $X^n-a \in K[x]$ is irreducible, $\alpha \in F$ is a root and $m \in \Bbb N$ a divisor of $n$, prove that degree of $\alpha^m$ on $K$ is $\frac n m$. 
What is the monic irreducible polynomial of $\alpha^m$ over $K$?

For the first part I have this:

K⊆K(α)⊆F (tower of fields) then [F:K]=[F:K(α)][K(α):K] degree of [F:K] is n, degree of [F:K(α)] is m then degree of [K(α):K] is n/m is this correct??

Thanks

Comment: Please, try a test case at least. Like $x^6-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. As it is written your question has all the earmarks of "somebody-do-my-homework". To dispel such thoughts you should show your own work and give other context (what potentially useful tools do you know of? et cetera). Take my suggested example in that spirit (an example is never a proof, but often gives you an idea of what's going on).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen

so, I have K⊆K(α)⊆F (tower of fields) then

[F:K]=[F:K(α)][K(α):K]

degree of [F:K] is n, degree of [F:K(α)] is m then

degree of [K(α):K] is n/m

is this correct??